# Total population of countries

Tags: python, csv

Write a function named "total_population" that takes a string then a list as parameters where the string represents the name of a CSV file containing city data in the format "CountryCode, CityName, Region, Population, Latitude, Longitude" and the second parameter is a list where each element is itself a list containing 3 strings as elements representing the CountryCode, CityName, and Region in this order. Return the total population of all cities in the list. Note that the city must match the country, name, and region to ensure that the correct city is being read.

I have pretty much everything setup nicely(I think) but I have a problem trying to sum the population at the end. I tried 3 ways of adding +1 each time and adding everything at the end but I can't seem to get it right.

```
import csv
def total_population(filename, cityinfo): # have CSV file and list that is a line with the function
    totalPop = 0
    #count = 0
    for str3 in cityinfo: # rep. the three catagorize 
        countryCode = str3[0]
        cityName = str3[1]
        region = (str3[2])  

    with open (filename, newline='') as f:    # the list contains 3 strings(Country code, city name, region)
        readCsv = csv.reader(f)
        for line in readCsv:
            if (line[0] == countryCode):
                if (line[1] == cityName):
                    if ((line[2]) == region):  
                        #count += 1
                        totalPop = totalPop + int(line[3])
                        #totalPop += int(line[3])
    return totalPop
```

The error message that I kept getting when submitting my code.

returned: 19561
expected: 25187

Comment: Could you somehow share the value of `cityinfo` and the csv file you're using for test?

Comment: The csv file is infinite and correlate with cityinfo. So example would be am,horom,07,1893,40.6541667,43.8822222. 3 points from csv and 3 points from cityinfo which is a list of itself. Dang I can't explain this well.. sorry

Comment: Also, I recommend you change the title and the description of your question to focus on the problem you're having (don't need to explain the whole exercise).

Comment: I know what you mean but this is the exact question from my homework and my problem is written on the second paragraph. Thank you for your advise.

Comment: Maybe one of your `if` statements isn't registering, so you are omitting part of the population?

Comment: I was wondering the same but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: The difference between returned and expected value is `5626`, does that correspond to anything? i.e. It may be a clue.

Comment: since the csv file is infinite, is pretty much useless to trace the outputs. I tried searching the population of many cities but it seems that the data is random and I can't pin point where the number is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to put the with/as statement in the for loop, so that it does it for every element in cityinfo, because it is not just one array. It is multiple, so you are only getting the first one

```
import csv
def total_population(filename, cityinfo):
    totalPop = 0
    #count = 0
    for str3 in cityinfo:
        countryCode = str3[0]
        cityName = str3[1]
        region = (str3[2])  
        with open (filename, newline='') as f:
            readCsv = csv.reader(f)
            for line in readCsv:
                if (line[0] == countryCode):
                    if (line[1] == cityName):
                        if ((line[2]) == region):  
                            totalPop = totalPop + int(line[3])
        return totalPop
```

Comment: Thank you helping but it seem to be not working, you're spot on with the code only picking up the first element the list. How can I make the code pick up all the elements and have the total of it. In this case,it will result in the total population.